# How can I avoid to write to the console?

Tags: javascript

I have to avoid to write console.log (also dir etc) in my server prod.

I've tried with

```
console = {};
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this bit of code:

```
  var console = {
    log : function (string) {
    //does nothing
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If often insert this piece of code to allow me to control console logging on client or server:

```
// must be in the global scope
if (typeof console === "undefined") {
    var console = {};
}

if (!console.log) {
    console.log = function() {
        // put whatever you want here or nothing if you want to stub it out
    }
}
```

Then, any `console.log()` statements will simply do nothing.

Doing it this way, allows code to actually use the real `console.log()` if it is defined, but prevents any errors if it is not defined.